# Why can't I set UIViewController's imageView in other UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have two UIViewControllers.In the firstViewController,there is a button ,the button action is

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
controller.imageView.image = image1;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

when the button is clicked,the SecondViewController's view come up ,but the imageview's image didn't change to "a.jpg".I need help ,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.I set image as a property instead of setting imageview as a property.I set the secondViewController's image in the firstViewController,like this:

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
controller.image = image1;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

then set the imageView in the secondViewController's viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like:

### FirstViewController

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
                                                  initWithAnImageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

### SecondViewController

```
-(id)initWithAnImageNamed:(NSString*)anImage
{
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: anImage];
    return self;
}
```

*Side Note: `a.jpg` should be included in the bundle.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of send the UIImage to the secondViewController you can send the string "a.jpg", and in the viewDidLoad of the seconviewController you implement the code

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: Thank for your advice ,but I still don't know why I can't just set the imageView in the firstViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not alloc init'ing the `UIImageView` object for `SecondViewController`.

Add

```
controller.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

Also make sure you have a.jpg in your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

A view controller doesn’t load its view until it needs to. When you access its `imageView` property, you’ll get `nil` back if you call it before the view has been loaded. You can force a view controller to load its view by explicitly calling `-view`:

```
[controller view];
```

It’s a kludge, but it works.